# C# - Get elevated admin privileges?

Tags: c#, permissions, system, admin, privileges

Is there a way to get the highest privileges (SYSTEM/NT-AUTHORITY) for my C# win forms application? **I am not talking about the normal administrator-privileges.**

After I confirmed the UAC window I like to elevate myself to NT-AUTHORITY. 
Is that possible without using a service?
Someone told me it can be accomplished by getting winlogon's Ttken And then start TrustedInstaller And duplicate it's token, then your program with highest availble privelleges.
Does anyone have experience with this, or can tell me more about that topic?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can impersonate a user on the local machine.

Check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158) for more information and code examples.